# VBS Public Variables

Tags: html, vbscript, global-variables, scope

I have VBS code in an html page that gets queries from an access database. I am trying to print the result of a query at the right place in the html using

`document.write(fDateDispo & " et " & tDateDispo)`

where fDateDispo and tDateDispo are public variables declared before all subs in the program. In one of my procedure (declared `Public Sub`)  I give the public vars their values with the query result. I used a msgbox() to confirm that the right values are attributed when the procedure runs.

My problem is that the value I give to the public variables during the procedure doesn't stay after it has been executed, they are just empty and only the "et" gets printed.

[EDIT]
here is the code:

```
public sub SendQuery(DateOne,DateTwo)
On Error Resume Next
    dim rs, passerelle, nbrAppels, c, stSQLpass
    dim Objet, nbrObjet, stSQLobj, rsObj
    dim Panne, nbrPanne, stSQLpan, rsPan
    dim SQLfromDate, SQLtoDate, stWhere, FromDate, ToDate


SQLfromDate="SELECT Min(Avis.[Date Appel]) AS [MinDeDate Appel] FROM Avis;"
SQLtoDate="SELECT Max(Avis.[Date Appel]) AS [MaxDeDate Appel] FROM Avis;"


ADOConnection1.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=G:\Planification\Planification\Stagiaires\Sébastien Leblanc\EntretienElectro_Backup2.mdb"
Set FromDate = ADOConnection1.Execute(SQLfromDate)
Set ToDate = ADOConnection1.Execute(SQLtoDate)

fDateDispo=FromDate.Fields(0).Value
tDateDispo=ToDate.Fields(0).Value

With rs
    .MoveFirst
    Do While Not .EOF
        passerelle = passerelle & .Fields(1).Value & Chr(9)
        nbrAppels = nbrAppels & .Fields(0).Value & Chr(9)
        .MoveNext
    Loop
    .Close
End With
' Remove the leftover tab character at the end of the strings.
passerelle = Left(passerelle, Len(passerelle) - 1)
nbrAppels = Left(nbrAppels, Len(nbrAppels) - 1)
' Objet cahrtspace1
With ChartSpace1
    .Clear
    .Charts.Add
    Set c = .Constants
    .AllowFiltering = True     
    .Interior.Color = "white"     
    With .Charts(0)
        .Border.Color = "white"
        .Interior.Color = "white"
        .Axes(0).Hastitle = TRUE
        .Axes(0).Title.Caption = "Passerelles"          'titre de l'axes des x
        .Axes(1).Hastitle = TRUE
        .Axes(1).Title.Caption = "Nombre d'Appels"      'titre de l'axe des y
        .SeriesCollection.Add
        .PlotArea.Interior.Color = "white"              du graph
        With .SeriesCollection(0)
            .Interior.Color = RGB(61, 166, 228)      

            .SetData c.chDimCategories, c.chDataLiteral, nbrAppels
            .SetData c.chDimValues, c.chDataLiteral, passerelle
        End With  

        .Type = c.chChartTypeColumnClustered
    End With
End With


    ADOConnection1.Close
End sub
```

i left out a couple of things because I doubt it has anything to do with it. its just other OWC objects and stuff...
I tried just attributing a value by doing `fDateDispo="date"` in the sub, but no luck.

[EDIT 2]

This is client-side VBscript. The sub is in the `<head>` and the document write is in the `<body>` of the html.the sub is called by an other sub set as window_load event.

[EDIT 3]

here is where i place my `document.write()` :

```
    <P style="PAGE-BREAK-AFTER: auto"><FONT face=Arial>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Les 
      données entre les dates
      <SCRIPT language=vbscript>

Document.write(fDateDispo & " et " & tDateDispo)

      </SCRIPT>
       sont disponibles.</FONT></P>
```

Comment: why you don't simply print inside the sub Or convert the `Public Sub` into `Public Function` and return the `OLEDB.Recordset` Object

Comment: Show us the code for your procedure (Public Sub). you most likely have parameters passed ByVal

Comment: ByVal doesn't exists in calssic ASP

Comment: This is client-side (IE-only) vbscript, not ASP. Am I right?

Comment: Can you show the code where you call this subroutine? It could be that you're calling `document.write(fDateDispo & " et " & tDateDispo)` _before_ you call `SendQuery()`

Comment: After seeing your edit, I think the window's `onload` event is fired after your `document.write()` is invoked in the body. I would try setting say, a `div`'s content to `fDateDispo & " et " & tDateDispo` just after `SendQuery()` is called in your `onload` event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I'm following this correctly, but to illustrate my comment:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="vbscript">
            dim var: var = Empty

            public sub subroutine()
                var = "blah"
            end sub

            public sub loadhandler()
                call subroutine()
                dim d: set d = document.getElementById("thediv")
                d.innerText = var
            end sub
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="call loadhandler()">
        <script language="vbscript">
            document.write "document.write('" & var & "')"
        </script>
        <div id="thediv"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

when loaded, the output is

> document.write('')
>   blah

meaning that the `document.write()` is called *before* `loadhandler()`, which is why `var` is `Empty` in the first line in the output

Comment: Ok, that could be my problem, do you have an idea as to how I could fix it?

Comment: Without seeing the context of your `document.write()` I couldn't give a good answer, but you could try as I've done here and populate a DOM element from within your onload handler after you call `SendQuery()`

Comment: Truns out that the div thing worked. Didn't event need to use document.write()!

Answer (score 1):

Is `document.write` supposed to be `response.write`?